# Get Logitech G402 software for Ubuntu 20.04 (Not Hyperion its just G402)

Tags: 20.04, mouse, logitech

I searched all over google every article every forum! I found NO information on this! I want to customize my Logitech G402 mouse and there is NO software offered by Logitech official website! All answers and information are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [piper](https://github.com/libratbag/piper). It should support your G402.

Piper is a GUI frontend to libratbag, a driver for various gaming mice on Linux. Alternatively you can use `ratbagctl` from the command line, which is installed along with piper if you follow the instructions.

Comment: Thankyou, This answer works! :D :D :D

Comment: However... The LED settings don't work and that probably means my mouse doesn't support it!

Comment: Oh wait, nevermind the LED settings do work!

Comment: Hey can you tell me why I get this error Something went wrong device has been reset to previous state

Comment: @JaydenW. No I'm afraid I can't help you with that error. When exactly does it appear? The Github site for both piper and the library track any known issues, you might have a look there.

Comment: Everything is working fine! Sadly though, my mouse doesn't support changing the color of the LEDs

Comment: Ah, ok. Have you tried it with ratbagctl? Sometimes that works more reliably.